# Firebase populate nested values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to populate students ?

```
"cohortStudents": {
  "cohort-id-4": {
    "cohortId": "cohort-id-4",
    "instructorId": "CZVLBcZ7lQe2OUcHdDLjW4OVFaB2",
    "students": {
      "student-id-1": true,
      "student-id-2": true,
      "student-id-3": true
    }
  }
}
```

So basically i can get data from `cohortStudents` by 
`https://[projectname].firebaseio.com/cohortStudents.json?orderBy="cohortId"&equalTo="cohort-id-4"`

And i will get object but `students: {}` will have still `student-id-1` etc

Is there a way to get data look like `students: { student-id-1: { name: '', email: '' } }`

Hope your help

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Database queries read child nodes from a single location only. There is no support for server-side joins.

To get the users that are referenced from `students` you will have to do a client-side join: loading each user individually.

I highly recommend using a Firebase SDK to do this, since it is optimized for this type of use-case. See [my answer to this question for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).